# Change timezone in cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have created *a SQL instance* on Google Cloud and I need to change the **timezone**. I already seen documentation, and I added the flag `default_time_zone` and set the value to `06:00`, but the console doesn't let me write the semicolon.

How can I write the value? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper format for the `default_time_zone` flag is `+/-HH:MM` e.g. to set it to GMT+6 you would write the value `+06:00`. Don't forget the leading zero.

To modify the timezone, update the Google Cloud SQL flag named `default_time_zone`. This or any other database flag can be updated as follows:

> 1) In the Google Cloud Platform Console, open an existing project by selecting the project name.
>   2) Open the instance and click Edit.
>   3) Scroll down to the Flags section.
>   4) To set a flag that has not been set on the instance before, click Add item, choose the flag from the drop-down menu, and set its value.
>  
>   5) Click Save to save your changes.
>   6) Confirm your changes under Flags on the Overview page.

When you add or modify these flags, your instance will automatically restart. **Note that you cannot modify flags on failover replicas.**

For further reading, see the documentation for setting [Cloud SQL Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#config).

Comment: What about Postgres?